# How to deal with participants recruited twice in a RDS (repondent-driven sampling) study?

Tags: r, sampling, epidemiology, networks, duplicate-records

I have RDS data and identified participants recruited twice during the study. How should I handle these duplicates? If I delete the second recruitment, it will disrupt the network. Can I consider the second recruitment as a seed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi! Is there a reason to not conduct entity resolution, as described in the following figure? https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5283838/figure/F1/ (in this example, the entity resolution consists of the two nodes "Sam J" and "Samuel J" being merged together in a single one, as they are actually the same person)